# Compile only part of a Handlebars.js template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I have a Handlebars.js template that I would like to complile piecemeal, as separate sections of this template correspond to different Backbone.js subviews. Is it possible to compile only the `#subsection` part of the following template?

```
<section id="widget">
    <h1>Widget Header!</h1>
    <nav id="nav">
        <!-- blah blah stuff here -->
    </nav>
    <section id="subsection">
        <!-- rah rah more stuff here -->
    </section>
</section>
```

**NOTE:** I realize that many of you will wonder why I shouldn't just use a file for each template. Currently I have only one use of this template, so I had no reason to split it up.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, for what you ask, no you cannont render a subsection of an Handlebars template.

What you'll want is probably multiple templates; one for each view. Then you can only rerender the view.

Answer (score 0):

Corectly you need few templates. One template for one subview.

But you can use jQuery (i dont know about zepto).

```
var html = widgetTemplate(); // your template    
var el = $(html);
var elementForSubvie = el.find('#subsection');
```

It works, but its bad way.